# MIMIC-III: many patients without prescription information?

Tags: mimic-iii

Of the 46,520 patients listed in the PATIENTS database, 7,157 do not appear in the PRESCRIPTIONS database. About half of these are newborns (age < 1 year), but there remains about 3600 patients w/ mean age 73 (approx normally distributed) who have no medication info.

Why is there no medication information on 8% of the patients in the database? Is this group random or are they special in some way?

Answer (score 0):

There was a transition from paper to electronic prescribing during the data collection, so these are likely patients who had paper prescriptions.